# django error for no reverse match

Tags: django

So I am teaching myself Django and had a good project going for awhile. I tried to add a registration module and set it up so that you could register for the site and only those who were logged in could see the content pages. Well in the process I have screwed something up and now none of the pages will load except for the admin module pages. When I start the development server I get a NoReverseMatch at / error. It says reverse for 'auth_logout' with arguments'()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.  I have tried to research anything I can find to figure out where I went wrong and have tried a number of different configurations to see if I can solve it but now I think I have screwed it up so bad I can't even get back to where I started. Can someone please take a look at see if they can point me in the right direction before I do too much more damage?

Here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, redirect
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpRequest, HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, Context
from app.forms import OrderForm,UserForm
from datetime import datetime
from django import forms
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from app.models import Order
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect
from app.models import *;



def MMIR(request):
    order_list = Order.objects.all();
    return render(request, 'app/MMIR.html',{'order_list':order_list});


class order_details(DetailView):
    model = Order
    template_name = 'app/order_details.html'




def New_Order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
           model_instance.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect('MMIR')
    else:
        form = OrderForm()
    return render(request, 'app/New_Order.html', {'form': form})




def home(request):
    """Renders the home page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/index.html',
        {
            'title':'Home Page',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        }
    )

def contact(request):
    """Renders the contact page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/contact.html',
        {
            'title':'Contact',
            'message':'Your contact page.',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        }
    )

def about(request):
    """Renders the about page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/about.html',
        {
            'title':'About',
            'message':'Your application description page.',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        }
    )

def register(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            registered = True

        else:
            print (user_form.errors)

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()

    # Render the template depending on the context.
    return render_to_response(
            'app/register.html',
            {'user_form': user_form, 'registered': registered},
            context)
```

and here is my urls.py:

```
`enter code here`enter code herefrom datetime import datetime
from django.conf.urls import url
import django.contrib.auth.views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
import app.forms
import app.views
from app.views import *
from django.views.generic import DetailView

# Uncomment the next lines to enable the admin:
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', app.views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^contact$', app.views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^about', app.views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^MMIR/$', app.views.MMIR, name='MMIR'),
    url(r'^New_Order/$', app.views.New_Order, name='New_Order'),
    url(r'^register/$', app.views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^MMIR/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', order_details.as_view(),      name='order_details'),
    url(r'^login/$',
        django.contrib.auth.views.login,
        {
            'template_name': 'app/login.html',
            'authentication_form': app.forms.BootstrapAuthenticationForm,
            'extra_context':
            {
                'title': 'Log in',
                'year': datetime.now().year,
            }
        },
        name='login'),
    url(r'^logout$',
        django.contrib.auth.views.logout,
        {
            'next_page': '/',
        },
        name='logout'),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Here is the actual error that I am getting:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'auth_logout' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:61568/
Django Version: 1.10.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'auth_logout' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Exception Location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 392
Python Executable:  C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\Visual Studio '
 '2015\\Projects\\DjangoWebProject2\\DjangoWebProject2',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\Visual Studio '
 '2015\\Projects\\DjangoWebProject2\\DjangoWebProject2\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\django_registration_redux-1.4-py3.5.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\Visual Studio '
 '2015\\Projects\\DjangoWebProject2\\DjangoWebProject2\\env\\Scripts\\python35.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\Visual Studio '
 '2015\\Projects\\DjangoWebProject2\\DjangoWebProject2\\env',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\Visual Studio '
 '2015\\Projects\\DjangoWebProject2\\DjangoWebProject2\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 6 Dec 2016 18:05:25 -0600
Error during template rendering

In template C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\app\templates\app\index.html, error at line 0
Reverse for 'auth_logout' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
1   {% extends "app/layout.html" %}
2   {% block content %}
3   
4   <div class="jumbotron">
5       <h1>LMMS Web Portal</h1>
6       <p class="lead">Vendor portal for entering shipping info</p>
7       <a href="{% url 'register' %}>Register Here</a>
8   </div>
9   
10  {% endblock %}
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _legacy_get_response
            response = self._get_response(request) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\app\views.py in home
            'year':datetime.now().year, ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py in render
            return self.template.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render
                    return self._render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py in render
        return compiled_parent._render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py in render
                return nodelist.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py in render
            url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DjangoWebProject2\DjangoWebProject2\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix
            (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns) ...
▶ Local vars
```

If there are other files you need to see to help diagnose the issue please let me know and I will post them.

Thanks for any help!
Max

Comment: Now might be a good time to learn to use version control software (i.e. git). Much easier to roll back changes when something doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah that is next on the list after this headache. I thought I was doing pretty well but apparently I got a little over confident and can't get it back now. I am using visual studio so I will have to look and see if it has any version control stuff built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your logout url

```
url(r'^logout$',
    django.contrib.auth.views.logout,
    {
        'next_page': '/',
    },
    name='logout'),
```

but it's named simply as `logout` rather than `auth_logout`. So you don't actually have a view named auth_logout in your urls.py. And I do believe the call to auth_logout lies in `app/layout.html`

Comment: Thanks for that...it helped for sure. I changed url pattern to 'auth_logout'  and everything worked, Until I hit the logout button and then I got the same basic error message for login. I changed that one the same way but it still only works if I go to the admin page and login again.

Comment: Actually I fixed it. It was a similar issue but just in another place in the code. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

e4c5 had the answer. I had a url pattern with a name 'login' but not one for 'auth_login'. I changed the name of the url and I am back in business.